# JComboBox + JPA

Tags: java, swing, jpa, jcombobox

I am currently stuck on a Java issue considering the java persistance API and JComboBox.

The issue is as follows:

I have a JDialog, whom I use to add something to the database.

In the view:

```
cbGenre = new JComboBox();
cbPublisher = new JComboBox();
```

What I want, is in these 2 combo boxes, to be loaded the values out of a List or ArrayList.
Standard, from what I found out, was a combobox only accepting a String array. I also found one example that uses ArrayList, whom I can work with.

Now the main question is:

I have 2 tables(only columns that matter will be listed):

```
games
id pk int
genre int

genre
id pk int
name varchar
```

They are connected via JPA in a M:1 relationship

so one game can only have one genre
one genre can have one or more games

How will I go about to add the retrieved genre names in the appropriate combobox, and when I press the save button, retrieve both the id of the name in the combobox and the id of that name?

Is this possible via an ArrayList, or does a JCombobox not allow value pairs?
The reason I want this, is when I save a game to the database, I need to have the selected genre id and add it to the database, and obviously, the user should not see an id, but rather Action, or RPG and what not.

Sorry if my question is a bit unclear. If it is, please do tell me so I can try to explain it better.

English is not my native tongue, whom you have probably noticed by now :)

Thanks for reading and I hope to find a solution soon. In the meantime ill browse trough google some more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combo box accepts any kind of objects. To display their value, it uses tht toString() method of the objects. So, you may have this code :

```
@Entity
public class Genre {
    // fields and methods

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

// in your GUI
List<Genre> genres = findAllGenresSortedByName();
this.cbGenre = new JComboBox(genres.toArray());
// ...
Genre selectedGenre = (Genre) this.cbGenre.getSelectedItem();
```

If Genre already have a toString method that you don't want to change, you may wrap a genre inside a dedicated class used for the GUI, and use a combo box of GenreWrappers rather than a combo box of Genres

```
public class GenreWrapper {
    private Genre genre;

    public GenreWrapper(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.genre.getName();
    }

    public Genre getGenre() {
        return this.genre;
    }
}
```

You should definitely read the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), and read the javadoc of the swing components you're using.

Comment: I guess this question got the best possible set of answers. +1 for your mention of the Swing tutorial (a **must-read** for all Swing developpers).

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. A very clear answer. Thanks for taking the time to read, and provide the answer. It provides exactly what I need. And I will read the documentation better from now on. Something I really need to do better, rather then just a general search. But meh, im learning alot about java already ^^ I started from scratch 2 weeks ago :) a +1 indeed!

Comment: actually, implementing toString just for showing up in a combo (or table or tree or whatever view wants to render the object) is a bad idea both for the original and the wrapper. The Swing'ish way of customizing the visual representation (including the string representation) is a custom xxRenderer. +1 for pointing to the tutorial :-)

Answer (score 2):

You seems not to have understanded a very important thing about Swing. It is, as far as I know, one of the best implementation of real MVC (as opposed to the torture that web MVC2 is to my mind).

consequently, each Swing component can be defined using the classical MVC idiom.

As an example, for your JComboBox, you have

- one view : the [`JComboBox`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) itself
- one model : the [`ComboBoxModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) which, in most cases, is instanciated from the Array of Strings you provide to it
- a set of controllers : the various event handlers you created to act upon various events int he view.

However, at another level, the components play other roles. If you examine the item rendering, you can then say that you have

- one model : the `ComboBoxModel`
- one controller : the `JComboBox`
- one view : the [`ListCellRenderer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) used to display those elements

To come back to your problem, let's suppose you change your `games` combobox model to hold not strings, but Game objects. Your combo box will then display strings like `Game@1548ea8`, which you can then change using the correct `ListCellRenderer`.

In that case, calling [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) will return to you a directly usable Game.

If you do the same thing for your Genre combo box, i guess the association code will be far simpler to write.

Comment: aah! this in combination with the previous answer, I could not ask for more. Thank you very much aswell. +1. Giving it game objects was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Riduidel: I did not mention ListCellRenderer in my answer, because they cause a problem when used to change the displayed String : the string displayed are the ones set in the renderer, but keyboard navigation in the combo box still uses the toString() method of the elements of the model. This is why I prefer using wrapper objects. I keep renderers for colors, icons, etc.

Comment: Well.. I already use the wrapper method. actually, I use a repository pattern combination with MVC, or trying to atleast, and it seems to work mostly for me. The repository pattern, I stole from my limited knowledge of ASP.NET MVC 2. but he, im still junior, so all these new things that pop are very interesting ^^ regardless of using it or not, i will still look at the list cell renderer, just to get familiar with it in the future.

Comment: Are you sure about keyboard navigation ? I've had very good experiences with these ListCellRenderers/ComboBoxModel combinations : the used ComboBoxModel ensures the items are in the order used by the ListCellRenderer, which in turn guarantees correctness of all navigation methods.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't even tought about keyboard navigation. I just assume users to click on their item.. I don't know if this is relative.. <:

Comment: @Riduidel: yes, I'm sure. Look at the source code for JComboBox.DefaultKeySelectionManager.

Comment: Wow, this one is positively crazy, man. +1 to you again ! Hopefully, this selection manager can be changed : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setKeySelectionManager(javax.swing.JComboBox.KeySelectionManager)